# Unable to print spreadsheet by using ExcelLibrary

Tags: c#, excel, dataset

i am using this [Create Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c)

What steps will reproduce the problem?
1. Create a spreadsheet using excellibrary
2. Open the spreadsheet in Excel
3. Try to print the spreadsheet

What is the expected output? What do you see instead?
Should print, instead get message 'Excel could not find anything to print'
If you copy the data to a new spreadsheet then it prints fine.

is there any solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

after some searching i have found this link

http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/issues/detail?id=31&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20ReportedBy%20Owner%20Summary%20Opened

by this i have solve this

Comment: Thank you. You saved my day. The project is not updating for a long time. Isn't it the time to fork it?

Comment: Beware! There's a code update to do in the project to ensure that the code work) Be sure to do the required modifications in the Issue 31 AND in the issue 137.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the recompiled dll with the print fix.

https://excellibrary.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=310010000&name=ExcelLibrary.dll&token=ABZ6GAfhAt8vF9GuExA0wgjRJnejNwrlVg%3A1412108599039